# MySQL Query: Fetching Data from 1 column with DateTime

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with 2 columns: DATETIME & S (see picture). Today we are April 10th, 2020.

What is the MySQL Query to fetch the last data (4384) from column S , which is TODAY() - 1day?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please add data onöly as text and please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What if TODAY()-1day does not have any data in `s` column?

Answer (score 0):

You need the function [`DATE_SUB()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub):

```
SELECT s FROM tablename
WHERE date = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other rows of S have no data i assume there are  NULL

do this to get the latest s

```
SELECT s FROM tablename
WHERE S IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY `Date` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

So you don't have to calculate the date. You seem to be unsure about it anyway.

Comment: But you could return the date too, so you know when the value is from.

Comment: Of course, the main problem was to get the correct row, adding more columns is a easy.

Comment: Sorry, I was addressing OP, or hinting that you should expand on the answer for how to turn that "unsure" into exact knowledge.

Comment: Look at his title where he speaks of 1 column to retrieve

Comment: Yes, and if you're specifically retrieving *yesterdays* record, there is no need for the date column, since you already know it. But you changed the code to return *latest* value, in which case you might want to know the date of that value, since it might not be yesterdays. Guessing/assuming it's yesterdays value is a bug waiting to blow up the code, and that is bad programming, so changing "unsure" to "sure" is a valid concern. Whether it applies to OP case is unknown, but a **good answer** will cover the ramifications of changing how the data is looked up.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT CURDATE();` will return you today date. `SELECT CURRENT_DATE()` and `SELECT CURRENT_DATE` will also do the same. When you apply plus(+) & minus(-) INTERVAL x DAY like this:

```
SELECT CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

it will return the yesterday date. Then you can apply that condition in `WHERE` like following:

```
SELECT s FROM table WHERE date=CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

This will return you `s` value of minus(-) 1 day interval